# $f\in C[a, b] $ Then show that $\frac{1}{M}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{dx} +m\int_{a}^{b} \frac1{f(x)} \mathrm{dx} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac mM} (b-a) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $f\in C[a, b] $. Assume that $m> 0$ and $M$ are minimum and maximum values of $f$ over the interval $[a, b]$.Then show that $\frac{1}{M}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{dx} +m\int_{a}^{b} \frac 1{f(x)} \mathrm {dx} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac mM} (b-a) $
$\bf{Try} :$
If we can say $\int_{a}^{b} \frac {1} {f(x)} \mathrm dx =\frac {1}{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)} \mathrm dx$ $\bf (\text{I don't know the proof of this claim} )$ then taking $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \mathrm dx =y$ we can apply A.M.-G.M. inequality to get
$\frac yM +\frac my \geq 2\sqrt{\frac mM} $.
$\bf \text{But how the factor (b-a) will come in the right hand side?} $
I want to know the answer of both the questions. A alternative way of solving the problem will be interesting to learn if exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{a}^{b} \frac {1} {f(x)} \mathrm dx =\frac {1}{\int_{a}^{b} f(x)} \mathrm dx$ does not hold in general – try it with $f(x) = x$ on $[a,b]=[1, 2]$.

But you are on the right track with the AM-GM inequality. If you apply it to the integrands, not to the integrals, then everything figures out nicely:
$$
\frac{1}{M}\int_{a}^{b} \, f(x) dx +m\int_{a}^{b} \frac 1{f(x)} \, dx
=  \int_a^b \left( \frac{f(x)}{M}+ \frac{m}{f(x)}\right) \, dx \\
\ge \int_a^b 2 \sqrt \frac mM \, dx = 2 \sqrt \frac mM (b-a) \, .
$$

This inequality holds as long as $m$, $M$ and $f(x)$ are strictly positive . The fact that $m$ is the minimum and $M$ the maximum of $f$ is not used.

Equality holds if $\frac{f(x)}{M}= \frac{m}{f(x)}$ on $[a, b]$, that is if $f$ is constant.

Comment: Well I wrote exactly the same but you posted faster lol

Comment: @Atmos: Sorry about that :)

Comment: Moving to integrands definitely made it simpler (+1). I leave my answer undeleted just for the sake of a bit different approach :)

Comment: I think $m>0$ is used otherwise we can't say $\frac 1{f(x)}$ is defined. Isn't it?

Comment: @Math-Learner Yes, and one could not use AM-GM otherwise.

Comment: @Math-Learner: Yes, that's why I said that $m$, $M$ and $f(x)$ must be strictly positive.

Answer (score 3):

Applying AM-GM once we get
$$\frac{1}{M}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x +m\int_{a}^{b} \frac1{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{m}{M}}\sqrt{\underbrace{\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x\int_{a}^{b} \frac1{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x}_{\text{we need } (b-a)^2 \text{ here}}}$$
So, we need to show that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x\int_{a}^{b} \frac1{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x \ge  (b-a)^2$$
which is obvious according to the [Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz_Inequality/Definite_Integrals) inequality:
$$(b-a)^2 = \left(\int_a^b 1~ \mathrm dx\right)^2 = \left(\int_a^b \sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{f(x)}}\mathrm dx\right)^2 \le \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x\int_{a}^{b} \frac1{f(x)} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Your approach help me understand where I made mistake. +1 and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Math-Learner You are welcome.